# Comparing two nested hashmaps

Tags: java

I have two nested hashmaps of the following structure(levels of nesting can vary)
The nested values can be instances of maps or arrays of maps.

```
{

  key1:[

    {

      nkey1:[

        nval1,
        nval2
      ]
    },
    {

      nkey2:[

        nval3,
        nval4
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I am doing an equals operation on two maps, which expects all keys to be identical. I want to exclude certain keys while comparison.

Say I should say I want to exclude key1::nkey2. How Do I accomplish this?
 A `map.keySet()` does not help with nested maps. How do I efficiently do a key by key comparison walking over this nested map?

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your map, i.e. include folded keys into main map. For your example you would have keys:

```
"key1"
"key1:nkey1"
"key1:nkey2"
```

In this case you won't need to use deep equals on each key, since all the levels would be eventually checked anyway. And you could remove any keys you want while traversing a single keySet().

Comment: That makes sense... But in cases of nkey1 and nkey2 having the same key names, we would be needing additional comparison

Comment: @Tania do you mean that keys of the same level might not be unique? Would it mean they are the same map and their contents could be merged, or they really should be separate maps?